# Why does python return an empty array when extracting meta description from urls?

Tags: python, cookies, meta, goose

I am trying to extract meta description using goose. I have written the following code. I also considered cookie handling. When I test using just one url, it works. However, when I iterate over an array of urls, an empty array results when I use the following code to extract meta description.

```
os.chdir("C:\Users\EDAWES01\Desktop\Cookie profiling")
data = pandas.read_csv('activity_url.csv', delimiter=';')
x="https"
url_data=np.array(data[(data.iloc[:,2]==1) & (data.iloc[:,1].str.contains(x))])[:,1]

#remove '~oref='

clean_url_data=[urlparse.urlparse(i)[2].split("=")[1] for i in url_data]

g=goose.Goose()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()) #for websites with cookie handling

website_meta_description=[g.extract(raw_html=(opener.open(urlw)).read()).meta_description for urlw in clean_url_data] 


print website_meta_description
```

Comment: `clean_url_data` must be empty which means `url_data` is also empty.

Comment: No it is not empty, I checked it.

Comment: What is the url? Also using requests would be a good idea.

Comment: it is an array of urls. retrieving the titles work though. how may i use requests in this instance?

Comment: In place of urrlib2, it will make you life a lot simpler, also bs4 would probably be a nocer api to use, I never heard of goose but it has not added a new version for over a year. If you can share a url I can show you how to get  what you want

Comment: this is the url: http://bp.velocityfrequentflyer.com/

Comment: @Technolohic27 No really, `url_data` must be zero length. You are using list comprehensions. The first one will create `clean_ url_data` to be the same length as `url_data`, the second will create `website_meta_description` to be the same length as `clean_url_data`. So if `website_meta_description` is zero length, then `url_data` must have been zero length. You aren't filtering any values.

Comment: @Technolohic27, there is no `description` in that html so it returns an empty string